# Symfony Custom Filters

Tags: php, filter, symfony-1.4

I have the code below adding a custom filter of a non-related model below but I cannot get it to filter. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
public function addLanguagesColumnQuery($query, $field, $value)
{
  $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
  $query->andWhereIn($rootAlias.'.journalist_id IN (SELECT journalist_id FROM journalist_language where language_id IN ('.implode(",", array_filter($value, 'strlen')).')');
  return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your schema?

I think the problem come from the table name you use for the subquery. You should use the doctrine name instead of the one inside the database.

So try to use `JournalistLanguage` (or the one defined inside your schema) instead of `journalist_language`.

Comment: JournalistOrganization:
    columns:
        organization_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
        journalist_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
        employment_id:  {type: integer, notnull: true}

Comment: finding it hard to post the whole schema

Comment: Updated your question with the revelant part of your schema: the `journalist_language` table for example.

Comment: I managed to sort the querying $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
 $query->innerJoin($rootAlias.'.sfGuardUser u');
 $query->innerJoin('u.JournalistLanguage j');
 $query->andWhereIn('j.language_id',array_filter($value, 'strlen'));
 return $query;